# Start async task in class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import asyncio

class Test:

    async def hello_world(self):
            while True:
                print("Hello World!")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

test = Test()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Blocking call which returns when the hello_world() coroutine is done
loop.run_until_complete(test.hello_world())
loop.close()
```

Is there a way to have the hello_world function starting to run from within the class (when an object of the class is created) without doing it from the outside?

Comment: Ummm, call the `Test.hello_world()` method from the `Test`'s constructor?

Comment: I would not recommend doing anything but initialize the object in `__init__`. That is a recipe for confusion. I would instead just have a `run` method and call `call_soon` in there.

Comment: The challenge is that the class is a subclass of the Gym AI class and I can't just throw in new methods to be called from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Is the *asynchronous constructor* trick what you need? To be able to achieve such usage:

```
async def main():
    test = await Test()
```

You just need to make the asynchronous constructor return `self` and add an `__await__` method to your class:

```
class Test:

    async def hello_world(self):
        while True:
            print("Hello World!")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return self

    def __await__(self):
        return self.hello_world().__await__()
```

Comment: hi, what if you have to parse an argument in the hello_world function? What would you do when calling the `__await__` funciton?